# Ajax with servlet and https not working on google app engine

Tags: java, jquery, google-app-engine, servlets, https

I have an app on GAE.
It works well when accessed via http not https.

I have a JS(jquery) function which looks like this:

```
function myFunc() {

                $.get('ser', function(respText) {
                     ...
                     });
                 };
```

which calls a servlet and update contents in a jsp page.

web.xml mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Ser</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ser</url-pattern>
```

In https request, the page load but the ajax request is not working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
It was in jQuery library linking.

I was using

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

changing http to https

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Solved the problem.